# HTML/CSS Floating a <div> to the right but it leaves a space between

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move a `div` to the right of the page to make something more complex, i.e. to have an image inside of it.

I want to make this image touch the right of the page but it always leaves a space. When I try to use `position`, it creates a side bar on the side and continues to have the space.

Here is an [image of the space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twngX.png)

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  background-image: url('wallpp.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  font-family: 'Comfortaa';
}

#logo1-div {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.saudacoes {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  width: 700px;
  left: -30px;
}

.saudacoes-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 112px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#index {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  left: -60px;
}

.nossahistoria {
  margin-top: 50px;
  float: right;
}

.nossahistoria-text {}
```

```html
<div id="logo1-div">
  <img src="logo1.png" width="250">
</div>

<div class="saudacoes">
  <img src="retangulo2.png" width="700">
  <div class="saudacoes-text">
    <h3>Olá bem vindo ao site oficial do Paula Cakes.</h3>
    <a>Aqui você poderá encontrar:<br></a>
    <div id="index">
      <a href="#nossahistoria-index" style="text-decoration: none;">•Nossa História.</a><br>
      <a href="#nossosprodutos-index" style="text-decoration: none;">•Nossos produtos.</a><br>
      <a href="#redessociais-index" style="text-decoration: none;">•Redes sociais.</a><br>
      <a href="#ondepodenosencontrar-index" style="text-decoration: none;">•Onde pode nos encontrar.</a><br>
      <a href="#infosdosite-index" style="text-decoration: none;">•Informações sobre a criação deste site.</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="nossahistoria-index" class="nossahistoria">
  <img src="retangulo2.png" width="600" height="1000">
  <div class="nossahistoria-text">
    <h2>Nossa História</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="nossosprodutos-index">
</div>
<div id="redessociais-index">
</div>
<div id="ondepodenosencontrar-index">
</div>
<div id="infosdosite-index">
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I suggest all new users visit [ask] for tips on writing questions that enable the community to help you. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Instead, create a [mcve] of the code _**as text** in the body of the question._ Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: @MurykoCasaril please paste HTML also into your question

Comment: i put it the important part

Comment: could you attach the screenshot with the question...the link isn't working for me and I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here without seeing it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to add `margin: 0` and `padding: 0` attribute to body selector.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  ...
}
```

Comment: didnt change anything

Comment: Try add the `box-sizing: border-box;` to `*` selector.

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

Comment: still nothing, i realy dont know what to do